# Convert string to RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I check a JavaScript string is in a RegExp format, then convert it to RegExp?

I found a way with RegExp, but the rule is too complex to make it right.

```
function str2Regex(str){
  var rule = /\/(\\[^\x00-\x1f]|\[(\\[^\x00-\x1f]|[^\x00-\x1f\\\/])*\]|[^\x00-\x1f\\\/\[])+\/([gim]*)/;
  var match = str.match(rule);
  return match ? new RegExp(match[1],match[3]) : str;
}
```

---

Now I'm using `/\/(.*)\/(?=[igm]*)([igm]*)/` which works.

Comment: Why do you need the check the validity of a regular expression? That seems like a serious issue.

Comment: I'm writing some route function, use a cfg object, which key is string or regex, value is handlerFn, because the object key must be a string, so I had to detect the key is a string or regex string, then change it to a Regex

Comment: I've seen your edit. Your solution fails on something as simple as `/**/i`. You really shouldn't try to guess if a string is correct as a regex, just let the browser finds it (i.e. use `try/catch` around `new RegExp`).

Comment: Another problem with your approach is that regex engines change. Supposing it's possible to find a regex validing regexes, it wouldn't be the same when new regex feature are introduced in javascript regex engines.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way, and probably the most correct, is to use try/catch :

```
try {
 r = new RegExp(str);
} catch(error) {
  // no good
}
```

You get a `SyntaxError` when the string doesn't match a well formed regular expression.

If you want to test a string whose value is like a compiled regular expression (for example `"/\b=\b/g"`, you can use such a function :

```
function checkCompiledRegex(str) {
  if (str[0]!='/') return false;
  var i = str.lastIndexOf('/');
  if (i<=0) return false;
  try {
    new RegExp(str.slice(1, i), str.slice(i+1));
  } catch(error) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: RegExp's param seems can't use / and igm. such as: ` "y".match(new RegExp("/y/i")) ` is null.

Comment: When you build a regex from a string, remove the "/" and the modifiers. `/y/i` is a compiled regex.

Comment: I know RegExp("\d+","igm"), so I'm searching for a regex to extract them from string "/\d+/igm"

Comment: if the regexp has a '/', this will not pass. for example, we can use /(w+)\/(\d+)/ to detect match "a/2" , then the regex string is  "/(w+)\\/(\d+)/" which can't pass your fn